# Laravel Session Query Unique Users

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel

I noticed a bug in my application when a user logs into my site from multiple computers, they are displayed twice in the list of logged in.  I managed to fix this by adding the `groupBy('user_id')` to my query, however I noticed something else wrong now: the user's last active field only updates for 1 of them.

`return $query->whereNotNull('user_id')->with('user')->groupBy('user_id')->get();`

To make this a bit clearer, prior to adding `groupBy`, lets say a user Bob logged in at 2 locations.  My logged in users would look like this:

`Bob Last Active 1 hour ago, Bob Last Active 6 minutes ago`

However, with the `groupBy`, it might show this:

`Bob Last Active 1 hour ago`

Even though the latest activity is 6 mintues ago.  I tried running a `sortBy('last_activity')`, however both ascending and descending have failed to fix this issue.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say with the question as-is because you don't explain what you're storing in that table and how you store it. I'm guessing you use a database session driver?

Anyhow, each user session is unique to a given location. This is why you get 2 entries when a user is logged in at multiple locations. A "location" here is considered different if it doesn't share cookies with another location (e.g. a private browsing window is enough). The session in Laravel is identified by the session cookie `laravel_session`.

What I suggest for your "last active" timestamp is to store it in your `User` model directly and update it when a user accesses your site. It makes much more sense to persist this uniquely with the user than trying to reconstitute the information from active sessions. Also, stale sessions are eventually removed and the information for a user would be lost.

#### update

[`group by`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) works with [aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp). What you want is something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(last_activity) 
FROM SessionTable WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id
```

With query builder:

```
\DB::table('session_table')
    ->select('user_id', \DB::raw('max(last_activity) as last_activity'))
    ->whereNotNull('user_id')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->lists('user_id', 'last_activity');
```

should return something like this:

```
[
 'user_id1' => 'last_activity1',
 'user_id2' => 'last_activity2',
 ...
]
```

Comment: I store the user_id in the sessions table and I also save the last_active to the user model so I am thinking of just using that approach.  I was hoping to figure out how to achieve this through a query though simply for the sake of knowing.

Comment: explained groupBy a bit

Comment: Sorry for the rather delayed response, my internet here is a little fubar right now.  Anyways, I am presently attempting to figure out how to do just what you said already(hopefully not having to use raw sql).  Presently, my `toSql()` looks like this `"select * from `sessions` where `user_id` is not null group by `user_id` order by `last_activity` desc"`

Comment: That got it.  Thanks mate.